# Merge battery and battery-life tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

What do you think: merge [battery](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery) and [battery-life](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-life) tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are very similar, merge them.

Since [battery](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery) is more general, let's keep that and just update the tags of [battery-life](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-life) to reflect this.

Since [battery-life](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-life) begins with the string `battery`, I don't think a synonym is needed.

Comment: Which tag should we keep? Should we make them synonyms of each other?

Comment: @Tom Great questions.  Updating...

Comment: @Tom Updated! :-)

Comment: +1 - I'm surprised these lasted as long as they did, good pickup

Comment: Worth checking: `battery-life` has a tag excerpt (and minimal tag wiki), while `battery` lacks both. I fully agree to the merge (already upvoted), but should we copy-paste the wiki first – or rather create a new one for `battery`? That step should be performed first then.

Comment: @Izzy I'll do that now.

Comment: @Izzy Done.  I rewrote, using the old ones as a base.  Probably need your approval to take effect.

Comment: Approved those edits. If no one sees a reason not to, we can merge [battery-life] -> [battery]

Comment: I'd say go ahead, @Undo – I couldn't find where to initiate the merge (already looked) :/

Comment: OK, merge completed :)